# Problem with output attempting to force itself all onto one page, but it does not fit

Tags: formatting

It was hard for me to come up with a title for this question. So, for one, my document is starting on the second page. The second issue is that I cannot seem to get everything to appear in my document. I have ten questions, but only 8 and part of the 9th show up. When I remove questions, the 10th one partially shows up. It's as if the entire document is trying to force itself all onto one page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is below. I'm stumped. Thank you so much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts, enumitem, fancyhdr, color, comment, graphicx, environ}
\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathbb{P}(#1)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\section{\fbox{1} \textnormal{Let \emph{A} = \{1, 2, 3\}. How many relations are there on A?}}


\section{\fbox{2} \textnormal{Let \emph{R} be a relation from sets \emph{A} to \emph{B}. Prove that Rng($R^{-1}$) = Dom(R).}}


\section{\fbox{3} \textnormal{Let \emph{A} = \{a, b, 1, 2, 3\}. Define \emph{R} = \{(1, 1), (a, a), (a, b), (1, 2), (2, 1), (a, 1), (a, 2)\}. Is this relation reflexive, symmetric, transitive, irreflexive, and/or antisymmetric? Explain. Draw a digraph of \emph{R}.}}


\section{\fbox{4} \textnormal{Let \emph{A} = \{a, b, 1, 2, 3\}. Let \emph{T} be an equivalence relation on \emph{A} such that aT2 and bT3. How many equivalence classes of \emph{T} are possible? List the equivalence classes for all possibilities.}}


\section{\fbox{5} \textnormal{Let \emph{Q} = \{(x, y) $\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ : $|x - y| < 1$\}. Is the relation \emph{Q} reflexive, symmetric, transitive, irreflexive, and/or antisymmetric? Prove or disprove that each property holds.}}


\section{\fbox{6} \textnormal{Prove that the collection \{$A_{t}$ : $t \in [0, 1)$\}, where each of $A_{t}$ = \{z + t : $z \in \mathbb{Z}$\} is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.}}


\section{\fbox{7} \textnormal{Write the addition and multiplication tables for $\mathbb{Z}_6$, the set of equivalence classes for the relation $\equiv$ (mod 6).}}


\section{\fbox{8} \textnormal{Define a relation $\leq$ on all words by agreeing that one word is $<$ another if an only if the first word comes before the second when arranged in alphabetical order. Show that this relation, called the \emph{lexicographic order}, is a total order. (If you don't know why this order is called lexicographic, look up the definition of this word in a \emph{lexicon}).}}


\section{\fbox{9} \textnormal{Draw the Hasse diagram for the poset \{\{2\}, \{3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{4, 5\}, \{2, 3 , 4\}, \{4, 5, 6\} ordered by set inclusion.}}


\section{\fbox{10} \textnormal{Let \emph{A} be a set and $\subset$ be the ordering for \emph{P}(\emph{A}). Let \emph{B} be a family of subsets of \emph{A}. Prove that the least upper bound of \emph{B} is $\bigcup_{X\in\emph{B}}X$ and the greatest lower bound of \emph{B} is $\bigcap_{X\in\emph{B}}X$}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you sure you want to use `\section`s here and not, say, and enumerate environment?

Comment: latex does not allow a page break after a section heading and (strangely!!!!) you only have headings and no text in the sections so there is nowhere to break the page.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I would consider using an `enumerate` environment to make things fit (easily) on one page and using math mode for math symbols (instead of `\emph`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\newcommand{\powerset}[1]{\mathbb{P}(#1)}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rng}{Rng}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Dom}{Dom}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\fbox{\arabic{enumi}}}

\item Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. How many relations are there on $A$?


\item Let $R$ be a relation from sets $A$ to $B$. Prove that $\Rng(R^{-1}) =
\Dom(R)$.


\item Let $A = \{a, b, 1, 2, 3\}$.  Define $R = \{(1, 1), (a, a), (a, b), (1,
2), (2, 1),$ $(a, 1), (a, 2)\}$. Is this relation reflexive, symmetric,
transitive, irreflexive, and/or antisymmetric? Explain. Draw a digraph of $R$.


\item Let $A = \{a, b, 1, 2, 3\}$. Let $\mathsf{T}$ be an equivalence relation
on $A$ such that $a\mathsf{T}2$ and $b\mathsf{T}3$. How many equivalence classes of $\mathsf{T}$ are
possible? List the equivalence classes for all possibilities.


\item Let $Q = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}~ :~|x - y| < 1\}$. Is
the relation $Q$ reflexive, symmetric, transitive, irreflexive, and/or
antisymmetric? Prove or disprove that each property holds.


\item Prove that the collection $\{A_{t} : t \in [0, 1)\}$, where each of
$A_{t} = \{z + t : z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.


\item Write the addition and multiplication tables for $\mathbb{Z}_6$, the set
of equivalence classes for the relation $\equiv$ ($\pmod 6$).


\item Define a relation $\leq$ on all words by agreeing that one word is $<$
another if an only if the first word comes before the second when arranged in
alphabetical order. Show that this relation, called the \emph{lexicographic order},
is a total order. (If you don't know why this order is called lexicographic,
look up the definition of this word in a \emph{lexicon}).


\item Draw the Hasse diagram for the poset $\{\{2\}, \{3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{4, 5\},
\{2, 3 , 4\},$ $\{4, 5, 6\}\}$ ordered by set inclusion.


\item Let $A$ be a set and $\subset$ be the ordering for
$P(A)$. Let $B$ be a family of subsets of $A$. Prove that
the least upper bound of $B$ is $\bigcup_{X\in B}X$ and the greatest
lower bound of $B$ is $\bigcap_{X\in B}X$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]